# Why I am getting an error while forward declaring root class in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, forward-declaration

Example:

```
@class MyRootObject;

@interface MyObject : MyRootObject
@end
```

Getting form XCode:

```
Class MyObject defined without specifying a base class.
```

MyRootObject class is:

```
@interface MyRootObject : NSObject

- (id)init;

@end

@implementation MyRootObject

- (id)init
{
   self = [super init];

   if(self){
      // some code here
   }

   return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Old reason: how is (was) the compiler supposed to deduce the size of an instance without seeing its base?

Comment: @H2CO3, "searching" for its declaration?

Comment: Without an actual declaration? How?

Comment: @AndrewShmig Xcode may be seen as an integrated environment, but in reality it just calls the compiler with a long list of command line parameters, so no matter how many files you include in Xcode, the compiler still works as if it was called from the command line or a make file. It doesn't search for data types or anything similar that isn't defined in expressly included files - and it has to be done for each .m file, as they represent a new task for the compiler for every invocation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't inherit from a forward-declared class. You need to `#include` the appropriate header instead.